# Batch - run Chrome for specific time

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I have basic batch file. I want to open first chrome page in fullscreen for 15 second then kill it and open second chrome page in fullscreen and again. But chrome starts and batch file doesn't count timeout. What am I missing?

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk first-chrome-page

timeout /t 5 /nobreak

taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk second-chrome-page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the command [***START /?***](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) to achieve your aim !

---

```bat
@echo off
Start "" chrome.exe --kiosk www.yahoo.com
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T
Start "" chrome.exe --kiosk www.stackoverflow.com
timeout /t 15 /nobreak
```

Comment: TY for your help. I deleted the "" and it's working.